# Padding isn't working TCPDF

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I'm working with TCPDF to convert some HTMLto PDF.
I can't put padding into my table, I have some borders and the text collapse with those borders, I've read that TCPDF doesn't allow some CSS.

Also I can't change the height of the table, so I'm working with `cellpadding="-1"`

There's my pdf.

[image]

[image]

in the middle I have `cellpadding="0";`

So... How can I set height to a `<tr>` or someone have some magic trick with TCPDF for a padding or margin?

`

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="-2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td width="50%" class="marcoNegro" ><p align="center" style="font-size:8px;">
      <font size="7"><strong>Contratante</strong></font><br>
    Inversiones Accionarias Landus S. A. de C. V.</p></td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="23%" class="marcoNegro"><p align="center" style="font-size:8px;"><font size="7"><strong>N&uacute;m. de certificado</strong></font><br>
    <?php  echo $rowLg->id_tabla;?></p></td>
    <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="23%" class="marcoNegro"><p align="center" style="font-size:8px;"><font size="7"><strong>N&uacute;mero de p&oacute;liza</strong></font><br>
    935492</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>`
```

Comment: try adding white borders that act as your padding. they work well in emails, and i'm guessing it can be done here too. you could do that to divs and not your tr's and td's

Comment: could you post the html you are using, the same goes for your css

Answer (score 3):

You need to use cellpadding. You need to build a more complex  in  structure which allows you to use cellpading on desired cells.